# Probability of finding a pattern

Tags: probability

A fair die is rolled sequentially. What is the probability of finding the pattern 5, 6 (i.e., 5 followed immediately by 6) before finding a 1?

Comment: Any thoughts?   I suggest looking at the various there aren't many...really, unless the game has ended, the only question is whether the prior roll was a $5$ or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be solved with an absorbing state Markov chain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

Answer (score 1):

Let x = Probability that 1 comes before 5,6

We want to find (1-x)

Lets define event A = 1 comes before 5,6

B = 1st output is 1.

C = First output is 5, second is 6

D = first output is either of {2,3,4,5,6} and second output is 5

E =  {2,3,4,5,6}  $ \times$ {2,3,4,5,6} - {5,6}

As you can see B,C,D,E are exclusive and exhaustive.

x = P(A|B)*P(B) + P(A|C)*P(C) + P(A|D)*P(D) +P(A|E)*P(E)

= 1*(1/6) + 0*(1/36) + P(A|D)*(5/36) + x*(24/36)

Let P(A|D) = y

Then simplifying the equation we get 
12x -5y = 6

Now consider the experiment where 0th throw resulted in a 5, then
P(1 comes before 5,6) = y

Let define the events for this experiment 
A = 1 comes before 5,6

B = 1st output is 1.

C = First output is 5

D = First output is 6

E = First output is either one of 2,3,4

y = P(A|B)*P(B) + P(A|C)*P(C) + P(A|D)*P(D) +P(A|E)*P(E)

= 1*(1/6) + y*(1/6) + 1*(1/6) + x*(3/6)

The resulting equation is 
3x-5y=-1

Solving above two equations we get 
x=7/9

Therefore 1-x=2/9.

so answer is 2/9